# Returning true if and only if a certain input is true

Tags: boolean-logic

I want to find a combination of logical operators on two inputs A and B that will return T when only A is true and F in every other case. Is this possible?

For clarity, the truth table should appear as follows.

```
A B Q
0 0 0
0 1 0
1 1 0
1 0 1
```

Comment: Slightly hackish implementation of material implication: `B < A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rephrasing the requirement often helps in such problems - you want to return true when A is true and B is not. Or, if you put it in operators: "a AND NOT b" (or `a && !b` in any reasonable programming language).

Comment: how do I select this as the answer?

Comment: @srcs You should see a greyed out checkmark ("v" symbol) below the answer's score. Click it in order to accept the answer - it should turn from grey to green.